# Remove a discord role when user removed a reaction python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So far I have a message that a new user can react to in a certain channel in discord that will assign them a role based on the reaction they choose (this part is working). I also want the role to be removed from the user if they remove their reaction to that message (this is what's not working). I get an error message saying: line 23, in on_raw_reaction_remove
role = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='War Thunder')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'

```
@client.event
# this works to assign a role
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    # channel and message IDs should be integer:
    if payload.channel_id == 700895165665247325 and payload.message_id == 756577133165543555:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "<:WarThunder:745425772944162907>":
            role = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='War Thunder')
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)

# this doesn't work in removing the role
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 700895165665247325 and payload.message_id == 756577133165543555:
        if str(payload.emoji) != "<:WarThunder:745425772944162907>":
            role = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='War Thunder')
            await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction%20remove#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.member) says, `payload.member` is only available if the `event_type` is `REACTION_ADD`. So, to get the guild, you must use [`payload.guild_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction%20remove#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.guild_id) and either:

- Use [`client.fetch_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch#discord.Client.fetch_guild):

  ```py
  async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
      if payload.channel_id == 700895165665247325 and payload.message_id == 756577133165543555:
          if str(payload.emoji) == "<:WarThunder:745425772944162907>":
              guild = await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
              role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='War Thunder')
              await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
  ```
- Use [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get):

  ```py
  async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
      if payload.channel_id == 700895165665247325 and payload.message_id == 756577133165543555:
          if str(payload.emoji) == "<:WarThunder:745425772944162907>":
              guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id=payload.guild_id)
              role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='War Thunder')
              await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
  ```

PS: Instead of writing `discord.utils.get()` everytime, you can write `from discord.utils import get` in your imports and write `get(iterable, **attrs)`.

Comment: I tried your ```discord.utils.get()``` example and got the following error when removing my reaction to the message:
`Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mrmet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_remove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload'`

Comment: When I tried your `client.fetch_guild()` example removing the reaction didn't remove the role or create an error.  It simply didn't do anything.  Also, thanks for the help I'm new to python and having trouble making sense of the documentation.

Comment: I don't really understant why you use `!=` instead of `==`. By making that change, you code should work. Also, delete that `self` argument in the function (I took some of my code and forgot to change it)

Comment: I was just gonna post I figured it out lol.  Here's the working code:
`async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 700895165665247325 and payload.message_id == 756577133165543555:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "<:WarThunder:745425772944162907>":
            guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
            member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='War Thunder')
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print(f"Removed {role} from {member}")`